# replace all instance of email addresses with "@example.com"

Tags: regex, perl

(another question, sorry but stressing for exam).

I have a file I am going to read in from STDIN. It has text and bunch of emails in the text.

```
"blah blah blah something john@smith.com blah blah james@john.com".
```

i want to replace all email addresses domain name with "@example.com". So the above becomes

```
"blah blah blah something john@example.com blah blah james@example.com"
```

Here is the code i have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while($line = <STDIN>){
  $line =~ s/'@'+'.com'\s/"@example.com"/g;

  print $line;
 }
```

Comment: Hmm. Is this a Perl exam? You are a long way from understanding regular expressions. What you have written appears to be a bad guess. You should focus on what you *can* do and make sure you know it inside and out. Don't waste time on improving your knowledge from *abysmal* to *poor* on the stuff you can't hack - it won't significantly improve your mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$line =~ s/(\S+)@\S+/$1\@example.com/g;
```

Comment: hey dude thanks.

Question explain the $1 in perl? I ve seen it but never understood it.

Comment: The LS (Left side) of the regex includes the captured group `(\S+)`.  That is so that I can enforce that there be something to the left of the @ sign instead of a space.  I also could've used a positive lookbehind assertion, but I figured that would be outside of your experience.  Each captured group is put into a numbered variable, $1, $2, $3 that can be included in the RS (right side) of a `s///` regex or outside of a `m//`.  In this case, I just wanted the $1 to precede your new email domain.